# Deselect a particular checkbox if any other checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a last minute request from a client to change form elements to multiple choice... so I've changed them to checkboxes and all is good. Now the checkboxes are generated dynamically and the only consistency between the them is the one will contain "none of the above" now I have the below:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            if (this.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf("None of the above") >= 0) {
                console.log("Is none of the above")
                if (this.checked) {
                    console.log("is checked")
                    $(this).closest('.js-form')
                        .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
                        .prop('checked', false);
                }
            }
```

This works, to a degree that if someone selects checkboxes and then selected "none of the above" it clears the other selections.

My issue is merely that I want an else: i.e if you haven't selected none of the above I want what ever selection you do mark the none of the above checkbox as checked, false.

if checkbox not equal "none of the above" checkbox, mark "none of the above" checkbox as checked, false.

So far all I seem to facilitate with variations of the code above is unchecking all the chekboxes

Comment: please share the relevant HTML so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty much there, but you mixed vanilla with jQuery and although that's fine, it can get confusing - jquery lets you use `$(this)` inside their event listener, so you tried `this` but its not the same thing here. So it's best to try and stick with one or the other, if not just for consistency and readability

I also added the bit that deselects the 'none of the above' if any of the other checkboxes get checked.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().text().trim().toLowerCase() === "none of the above") {
    console.log("Is none of the above")
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      console.log("is checked")
      $(this).closest('.js-form')
        .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
        .prop('checked', false);
    }
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.js-form')
      .find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().text().trim().toLowerCase() === "none of the above") $(this).prop('checked', false)
      })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='js-form'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' /> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' /> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' /> Checkbox 3</label>
    <label><input type='checkbox' /> Checkbox 4</label>
    <hr>
    <label><input type='checkbox' />None of the above</label>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks I see what I did. Opted to do it in straight Javascript in the end. But will leave this up, as it may help someone else